# android 13 does not load and stays on "Booting device"

Tags: android, qemu, genymotion

**its not loading android 13 and it shows this in log**
[image]

i was trying to load android 13 and it just does not load what is it trying to do and why does it need to do what its trying to do and sometimes it will say [Genymotion Player:3108] [debug] DeviceConnection error: "Connection reset by peer" what does this mean?

Comment: Does your network block some websites?